# How to detect in scanf() when there is no input?

Tags: c, input, scanf, restriction

The while loop below is supposed to be terminated when there is no input, how can this be achieved?
Also what is the analogous of `scanf("%1d" &n)` in C++?

I have tried it using return value of `scanf()` and using `n==NULL` as condition but both of them lead to an infinite loop.

```
int n;
int arr[100];
int i=0;
int r = scanf("%1d",&n);
while(r==1)
{
    arr[i++]=n;
    r = scanf("%1d",&n);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no input"?

Comment: `scanf` doesn't accept a void input. To terminate scanf you have to use ctrl-D (Linux/Unix). In this way you obtain `scanf` returns -1.

Comment: You've tagged this as C but mention C++ in the question, which is it?

Comment: OP tagged this as both `c` and `c++`; @πάντα-ῥεῖ then removed one of the tags.

Comment: You can use a timer to determine no input was given in the last minute and send a sigtern

Comment: Despite the downvote, I think the code in my answer might be a solution nearby the solution you are looking for. (I edited the code after the downvote).

Comment: Ajay Kushwaha, "there is no input" is unclear.  `scanf("%1d",&n);` will wait for input as long as `stdin` is open.  What keys do you press to indicate "nothing" is inputted?

Comment: NO input means eg: input: 2345678. And this program will read it as 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 after reading 8 it should terminate. This is what I wanted to ask

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read only one digit number, you can do it with getchar().

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    int arr[100];
    int i = 0;
    int enter = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        n = getchar();

        if (n == 10 && enter) break;

        if (n == 10) 
        {
            enter = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            enter = 0;
            n -= 48;
            arr[i] = n;
            i++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(1)` shall be "dangerous" when `i` becomes more than 99.

Comment: Don't use `10` when you're really thinking of `'\n'`. Unlike some other numbers, 10 comes with the baggage of being the base used for counting by most of humanity.  Similarly with `48` — that should be written `'0'` (but it doesn't have as much spare overloaded meaning as 10).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `scanf` as in the code below.

The code also verifies:

- that you don't insert more than the number of elements in the array `arr` (`ARRDIM`).
- that the input of incorrect digits (I.E.: 'a') doesn't create loops.

You have to hit `CTRL-D` (Linux/Unix) to stop the data input. (Windows should terminate using `CTRL-Z`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
#define ARRDIM 100

    int n;
    int arr[ARRDIM];
    int i=0;
    int r=0;

    do
    {
        printf("Insert element %d: ",i+1);
        fflush(stdout);
        r = scanf("%1d",&n);
        if (r>0) {
           arr[i++]=n;
        } else if (!r) {
            printf("Error inserting element: %d ",i+1);
            puts("You have to insert only numbers.");
            // flushes the wrong input
            while ( (r = getchar()) != EOF && r != '\n' );
        }

    }  while(r!=EOF && i<ARRDIM);

    puts("Inserted values:");
    for(r=0;r<i;r++)
        printf("%d\n",arr[r]);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: This code doesn't consider the case where the single input contains more then 1 single numerical digit. If you insert more than 1 digit per input you obtain that the next fields are loaded and if you insert more digits than the max number of digits fitting in the array the overloaded digits  remain into the stdin buffer.

Comment: I'd go for `while (i < ARRDIM && 1 == scanf(...)) { arr[i++] = ...; }`

Comment: Now my code controls also the input of not correct chars ... where `scanf` might returns 0.

Comment: @alk, I like your code! But it doesn't control the errors due to the input of wrong digits ... as said me melpomene.

Comment: @melpomene, I corrected my routine and now it should be good! I think. :D

Comment: `while (i < ARRDIM && 1 == (r = scanf(...))) { arr[i++] = ...; }` Use `r` after the loop to log what happened: No input (`0`) or wrong input (`-1`).

Comment: @alk, Yes, but in this way you cannot ask for all values till CTRL-D and if r is 0 scanf cannot be used more.

Comment: I edited the code adding some `printf` \ `puts` messages to better explain the code behaviour. :)